# Tutorials for problems with Xilinx's microblaze IP Stack

Tags: tcp, embedded, low-level, ip-protocol, microblaze

My team is using the microblaze and we're having some trouble with the ip stack.
I am usually not an embedded programmer but I would like to learn how to help.
Are there any tutorials about IP stacks? What are they? How are they programmed? How can I troubleshoot problems in the IP stack?
Basically any info would help me.

Thanks in advance,
Omer.

Edit:
According to our electronic engineer this is the problem:
We are using lwIP on the Spartan-3A DSP S3D1800A circut while using BSB and it microblaze on it.
We're trying to use the Echo Server demo that has been given to us and it's supposed to open a port to telnet and echo any message recivied from there but it doesn't do that.
We have absolutly no idea what's wrong there.

Comment: You don't say what sort of trouble you're having, so it's a little hard to give useful advice on troubleshooting. Are you seeing memory leaks, protocol violations, performance issues, system integration issues?

Comment: It's the 'I have no clue what is wrong' trouble. Nothing that you mentioned though, it just doesn't ping.

Comment: Why not just put Linux: http://www.monstr.eu/wiki/doku.php on it?

Comment: @Maciek Sawicki: Is the Linux microblaze port stable? Can it be used in commercial products?

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP lean by Jeremy Bentham

http://www.iosoft.co.uk/tcplean.php

Comment: Is there any free e-book/tutorial on the internet?

Comment: The RFC's are quite readable. Other books to consider: Comer & Stevens "Internetworking with TCP/IP" volume II , ANSI C version. This book is very complete, but is not stripped down at all for small devices.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's good to know which IP stack you're using. Are you using e.g. [lwIP](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/) stack or [uIP](http://www.sics.se/~adam/uip/index.php/Main_Page) stack? They are popular stacks for embedded platforms. You could have a look at the documentation for those stacks, for an introduction to the main concepts. There are functional examples around for those stacks on a variety of platforms.

**lwIP**

- [Documentation wiki](http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/LwIP_Wiki) (a bit sparse)
- [Function documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/lwip/)
- [lwIP Example from Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1026.pdf) (it includes some Microblaze material)

Comment: I am using lwIP but I haven't found any useful documentation on any of their sites (there is an old version and a new one)

Comment: Okay, I've added a link to an lwIP documentation wiki. It's a bit sparse perhaps.

Comment: The documentation wiki looks useless and we've already read the Xilinx manual, the first demo is actually what we're trying to run. The doxygen documentation might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as troubleshooting goes, you can search for relevant keywords on [Xilinx forum.](http://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/) 
Different IP stack implementations for Microblaze have been around for a few years, so chances are you'll find a lot of useful stuff there.